# Unknown class RAMAnimatedTabBarItem in Interface Builder File

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, storyboard

I'm attempting to add an external library written in Swift to my Objective-C project.  The library is here:

https://github.com/Ramotion/animated-tab-bar

I followed their instructions by adding the `RAMAnimatedTabBarController` to my project, then modifying my `Tab Bar controller ,  Tab Bar items  to utilize the custom class in the storyboard.

It keeps crashing with *unknown class* messages in the logs, so even though autocomplete on the custom class worked, it clearly can't see/compile the project files:

```
2015-05-01 14:59:26.309 <project>[xxxx:xxxxx] Unknown class RAMAnimatedTabBarItem in Interface Builder file.
2015-05-01 14:59:26.350 <project>[xxxx:xxxxx] Unknown class RAMAnimatedTabBarController in Interface Builder file.
2015-05-01 14:59:26.353 <project>[xxxx:xxxxx] Unknown class RAMBounceAnimation in Interface Builder file.
```

I've read a bunch of stuff about including swift header files in order to interchange using objc and swift in your projects, but they mention importing into your `ViewController` classes (of which I don't have since TabBar and NavController are only in the storyboard).

[How to access both Objective-C and Swift classes from same storyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24020610/how-to-access-both-objective-c-and-swift-classes-from-same-storyboard)

Still pretty new with storyboards and I feel like I'm missing a critical piece here.  Help!

Comment: Crazy nobody else has run into this... I'm still stuck.

Comment: I've run into this same problem, have you figured it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to get it working...

1. Set Tab Bar controller to RAMAnimatedTabBarController
2. Select tab bar item > Identity Inspector and set class to RAMAnimatedTabBarItem and module to RAMAnimatedTabBarController
3. Drag in your object and hook it up as per the video tutorial here: http://vimeo.com/112390386
4. Click the object and set class to (anything you want, e.g. RAMBounceAnimation) and ensure the module is RAMAnimatedTabBarController

Also make sure :

- setting the module in the identity inspector on the animation object
- you set a duration on the object attribute inspector and press enter
- Setting module to RAMAnimatedTabBarController

[image]