# pushViewController from Objective-C class to Swift

Tags: objective-c, pushviewcontroller

I am trying to push ViewController from Objective-C class as bellow:

```
ProductDetailVC *aObjVC = [appDelegate.mainStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ProductDetailVC"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:aObjVC animated:YES];
```

But it getting crashed due to below reason:

> "Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard () doesn't contain a view controller with identifier
>   'ProductDetailVC''"

**I even assigned identifier "ProductDetailVC" in storyboard**

[image]

Comment: Where are you calling this method from?

Comment: You have set the identifier to `ProductDetailVC ` in the `Storyboard` right?

Comment: @dirtydanee he has mentioned he did that already in the original post. First editor had removed that info.(and you've approved that wrong edit ;) ) I've added it back.

Comment: @sleepwalkerfx : I am calling this from objective c class. As i have added swift class in my objective c class but when i going to pushviewcontroller its fail

Comment: @dirtydanee Yes I have set identifier to ProductDetailVC in storyboard

Comment: @NiravPatel check module under the class name, is it nil/empty?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if your storyboard isn't nil?

Try this:

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"YOURSTORYBOARDNAME"
                                                         bundle: nil];

YOURVIEWCONTROLLER *controller = (YOURVIEWCONTROLLER*)[mainStoryboard 
                    instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"YOURVIEWCONTROLLERID"];
```

Comment: Storyboard isn't nil, i am calling other objective c classes from this inside main storyboard all works only in case of swift class not working.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the cause is, your `appDelegate.mainStoryBoard` does not holds a reference to your actual storyboard. You don't need to keep a storyboard reference in your appdelegate to push a viewcontroller. You can do it by calling `self` instead,

```
ProductDetailVC *aObjVC = [self.mainStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ProductDetailVC"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:aObjVC animated:YES];
```

Comment: I have tried with "self.storyboard" but even its not works.

ProductDetailVC *aObjVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ProductDetailVC"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:aObjVC animated:YES];

Comment: check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24020610/how-to-access-both-objective-c-and-swift-classes-from-same-storyboard

Comment: Thanks! Just able to resolve it by above link, Created another storyboard and put viewcontroller in new storyboard. And works perfect. but its not works in my old storyboard need to create newer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Double check the **class_name** "ProductDetailVC".
2. Remove the **class_name**, and type again and press enter.
3. then check the **identifier**.
4. **Module** should not nil

[image]

```
    ProductDetailVC * productDetailVC = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ProductDetailVC"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:productDetailVC animated:TRUE];
```

Comment: Yes I have added already, Please check my question again i have added screenshot.

Comment: @NiravPatel whats your storyboard name ?

Comment: "Main" Default storyboard name.

Comment: Yes i tried that way as well but not works, just able to resolve it by creating new storyboard and created viewcontroller in that storyboard and after that its works.

Comment: @NiravPatel then your connections must be broken for some outlets

Comment: I think all proper, might be issue need to upgrade storyboard. I checked below link and there mentioned that i have create Main in old xcode and newer xcode i create swift class so need to upgrade storyboard.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24020610/how-to-access-both-objective-c-and-swift-classes-from-same-storyboard